# Is it possible to make constructor static in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, static, initialization

I read about a static constructor in TypeScript and tried it myself but it doesn't work. I want to initialize a static variable by that (the method shall only be called once) but I get the following compiler error:

> Error: 'static' modifier cannot appear on a constructor declaration.

Code:

```js
export class DataManagement {
  private static subjects: string[];

  static constructor() {
    DataManagement.subjects = [];
    //some more code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just initialize the `subjects` field on class level, eg.: `private static subjects: string[] = []`? Why would you want to re-initialize it on each constructor call?

Comment: Well, thanks! It does work!
So this is crap? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/265

Comment: @BalázsÉdes Because that's just an example - of course there is a lot of other code in there as well... But it is unnecessary to share the code... And I don't want to initialize it on each constructor call but only once - because of that a **static** constructor. Like static initialization blocks in Java.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

While other languages like C# do have static constructors, TypeScript (and JavaScript) do not have this feature. That said, you can still define a function statically which you invoke yourself. First, let me explain in which cases you might need a static constructor before I go over the options you have.

**When to use a static constructor**

A static constructor is useful in cases in which you need to calculate the value of a static attribute. If you just want to set an attribute (to a known value), you don't need a static constructor. It can be done like this:

```js
class Example {
    public static info = 123;
    // ...
}
```

In case you need to compute the value, you have three ways to "simulate" a static constructor. I go over the options below and set the static attribute "info" in each sample.

#### Option 1: Call an initialize function after the class is declared

In the code below, the function `_initialize` is statically defined in the class and invoked immediately after the class is declared. Inside the function, `this` refers to the class, meaning that the keyword can be used to set any static values (like `info` in the sample below). Note, that it is not possible to make the function private, as it is invoked from outside.

```js
class Example {
    public static info: number;

    public static _initialize() {
        // ...
        this.info = 123;
    }
}
Example._initialize();
```

#### Option 2: Directly invoke the function inside the class

The second option is to use a function, which is directly called after its creation inside the class. The function only *looks* like its part of the class, but has no relation to the class itself (except being defined inside of it), meaning that you cannot use `this` inside the function.

```js
class Example {
    static info: number;

    private static _initialize = (() => {
        // "this" cannot be used here
        Example.info = 1234;
    })();
}
```

#### Alternative: Calculate a single attribute

Based on the same idea as option 2, you can calculate a single attribute by returning the value. This might be handy in cases where you only want to calculate one attribute of the class.

```js
class Example {
    public static info = (() => {
        // ... calculate the value and return it
        return 123;
    })();
}
```

### What to use

If you only want to calculate a single static attribute, you might want to use the last (*alternative*) approach. In case you need to do more complex calculations or want to set more attributes, I recommend using option 1 if you don't mind the function being public. Otherwise, go with option 2.

Note, that there is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/265) in the TypeScript repository, that contains some more discussions regarding option 1 and 2.

Comment: For option #2 in vsCode I get an error:  '_initialize' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133).  I have to use // @ts-ignore to suppress this error.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

Note that beginning with TypeScript 4.4, static block initializers are supported... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-rc/#static-blocks

```
class Foo {
    static Foo.count = 0;

    // This is a static block:
    static {
        if (someCondition()) {
            Foo.count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31369888)

Comment: Typescript is Friggin awesome.  They have to compile to javascript, which must make it easier innovate.

Answer (score 3):

`Symbol()` can be used for this, cleanly with restricted public access.

```
const STATIC_INIT = Symbol(); // gives you a unique identifier

class MyClass {
  public static[STATIC_INIT] = () => {
    // Your static init code here
  }
}

// Call the init once
MyClass[STATIC_INIT]();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate static constructor using static code in your .ts file.

Let's say you have class which serves a single purpose of parsing parameters and merging them with some defaults.

Just add call after you class declaration.

Here is an example:

```js
export class Env {
    private static _args: {}
    static get args() {
        return this._args;
    }

    static _Initialize() {
        // load settings from Environment
        process.argv.forEach(s => console.log(s))
        this._args =  Object.assign({}, defaults, this.parseCmdLine())
    }
}
Env._Initialize();
```

Example TS Application: https://github.com/v-andrew/ts-template

It works exactly as static constructor with who caveats:

- It could be called multiple times
- It could be called by other users of `Env`

To nullify those issues redefine _Initialize in the end of `_Initialize`:

```js
        this._Initialize = ()=>{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an object :) :

```
 const dataManagement: { subjects: string[] } = {
   subjects: []
 };

 export { dataManagement };
```

Answer (score -1):

So the use of a static constructor is a bit of a misnomer. your are not try to make the constructor method static, but try to create a static instantiation method. It can be named whatever you want. I've used initialize, personally.

You can have your constructor method be essentially blank

`constructor() {}`

And then have a static initialize method

`static initialize(): <type-to-use> { //initialization logic };`

usually in the initialize method you want to invoke the constructor with the keyword new, and after that, default your properties.